# No Signature of method withHttp Rest Plugin Grails 3

Tags: rest, grails

i tried to install rest plugin like [this](https://github.com/bobbywarner/grails-http-builder-helper/issues/22) step, i when i tried to  use `withHttp` from Service...

i get this error..

```
ERROR com.test.project.sendService- No signature of method: com.test.project.sendService.withHttp() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, 
com.test.project.sendService$_sendText_closure2) values: [[uri:http://myweb.web.id], com.test.project.sendService$_sendText_closure2@43cec0c7]
```

as i know under grails 1.x and 2.x, this plugin still called "Rest" but under grails 3,it changed it to **Grails Http Builder Helper**..

see this [page](https://github.com/bobbywarner/grails-http-builder-helper)..

is this a bug from **Grails Http Builder**'s plugin?